# WiFi sync with computer connected by cable to the WiFi router?

Tags: data-synchronization, wifi, ios

My computer does not have a WiFi card, so I connect it via LAN cable to my router. My iPhone is connected to the WiFi signal of that router. Is there some kind of magic that will enable me to use WiFi sync with my computer?

Comment: Silly me, it simply works. The question can be deleted.

Comment: Actually, this is a good question and should be kept.

Comment: How did you get it to work? My computer is connected with a cable too, and I can't get it to work. Have plugged my iPhone into power too. Does it only work with Macs or something? (I'm on Windows)

Comment: You should enable wi-fi syncing first. Plug the iPhone to the computer using a cable and set the correct option in iTunes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if they are both on the same network, there is nothing special you need to do.

Comment: I will add some subtle caveats to this: Apple uses some network trickery to make the devices see each other, so routers/firewalls *can* interfere. Unfortunately as far as I'm aware there's no single source of truth on what ports/protocols are used so YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

First off it's not a stupid question and secondly it's not on the same network. Your PC is on the LAN, that is one network and you iPhone using wifi is a different netowrk. The iPhone sends a Bootp broadcast on udp port 67. This broadcast will not be seen on the second network (LAN). I searched high and low to find out how to get this to work and there is no solution anywhere. So I decided to figure it out myself.  The broadcast will not go across 2 networks normally. Fortunately I have a firewall that allows bridging. It also allows me to keep policy based functions between the 2 networks. The bridging allows the broadcast. After the broadcast it does a multicast on udp port 5353. Then the sync works.

To get this working on your firewall/router look for bridging for that make and model. In some cases there may not be any security between the networks once you do this. This is only a problem if someone hacks into your wifi.

Comment: On my router WiFi and ethernet are the same network - I think you have an odd setup here